# Clear all filters remove the custom filter options

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When I click the `clear all filters` option from the table menu, filter data gets cleared and worked fine, but it has cleared the custom filter option I have added for two column fields. After then, custom filters are not working based on the conditions I have added. Please find the sample code I have created in [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hDqtdzpfRfkDptxBERsb?p=preview)

In the provided sample code, age filters are working fine based on the filter conditions added. When selecting the `clear all filters` option, it clear all the filter text entered, after then text entered in age filter ie: greater than or less than is filtered based on default `contains` only and the custom filter I have added was not filtered anymore. It should be a major bug in business perspective.